# what is oci_bind_by_name for?

Tags: php, oracle

what is [`oci_bind_by_name`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.oci-bind-by-name.php) for? I read the php manual and cannot understand anything. Please someone explain it to me

look at this example :

```
$name = "O'Reilly";
$stid = oci_parse($mycon, 'INSERT INTO CUSTOMERS (NAME) VALUES (:nm)');
oci_bind_by_name($stid, ':nm', $name, -1);
oci_execute($stid);
```

what is `-1` for?

Comment: please review the answers you have been given so far and either accept the one that solved your problem or update and improve your question to point out why none of these solve your problem, so people have a chance to improve their answers. thanks.

Answer (score 11):

It binds values to named parameters:

```
$name = "O'Reilly";
$stid = oci_parse($mycon, 'INSERT INTO CUSTOMERS (NAME) VALUES (:nm)');
oci_bind_by_name($stid, ':nm', $name, -1);
oci_execute($stid);
```

So when you run that query `:nm` will be `O'Reilly`. The `-1` means, the bound value should be as long as the variable. It's the default value. You don't have to set it. As long as you are only binding existing variables, you don't need to bother.

You want to use this method because

> Binding allows the database to reuse the statement context and [caches from previous executions of the statement](http://www.oracle-developer.net/display.php?id=503), even if another user or process originally executed it. Binding reduces [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) concerns because the data associated with a bind variable is never treated as part of the SQL statement. It does not need quoting or escaping.

which means it is **more secure** and has **better performance**.

Comment: so its like `mysql_escape_real_string`? and look to this example  `$name = "O'Reilly";
$stid = oci_parse($mycon, 'INSERT INTO CUSTOMERS (NAME) VALUES (:nm)');
oci_bind_by_name($stid, ':nm', $name, -1);
oci_execute($stid);` what is `-1` for?

Comment: @user No, it's not like `mysql_real_escape_string`. It's much more like `mysqli_stmt_bind_param` or `PDO::prepare`. The `-1` is the default value for the maximum length the param value can be. It means "as long as the value is".

Answer (score 1):

oci_bind_by_name method is specifying that the value for :nm is "O'Reilly"
-1 is default value ... so need to bother. if you are specifying other value that will tell the method to have the length of the value in :nm.

Comment: I know it's too late, but -1 is the `maxlength`. http://php.net/manual/en/function.oci-bind-by-name.php