# What can I use in php instead of (mysqli_real_escape_string)

Tags: php, mysqli, oracle-call-interface

I have connected to oracle using `oci_connect` and I get this error:

> Warning: mysqli_real_escape_string() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, resource given in

So I'm trying to change `mysqli_real_escape_string()` to work with oci...

Here is my code:

```
$condition = '';

   $query = explode(" ", $_GET["search"]);
   foreach($query as $text)
   {

        $condition .= "VIDEO_TITLE LIKE '%".mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $text)."%' OR ";
   }
   $condition = substr($condition, 0, -4);
   $sql_query = "SELECT * FROM TBL_VIDEO WHERE " . $condition;
   $result = oci_parse($connect, $sql_query);
   oci_execute($result);
   if(oci_num_rows($result) > 0)
```

Comment: Why do you think you can use a mysql API with oracle?

Comment: i didnt, i just wanna change code from this link. https://www.webslesson.info/2016/05/how-to-search-multiple-words-at-a-time-in-mysql-php.html into oci_connect

Comment: Just use a prepared statement instead. It's safer than what you are doing and it removes the need to call a function like `mysqli_real_escape_string` to sanitise your data

Comment: @Nick any advise on where should i start?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [what is oci\_bind\_by\_name for?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5688572/what-is-oci-bind-by-name-for)

Comment: @KwanheeHwang http://php.net/manual/en/oci8.examples.php http://php.net/manual/en/function.oci-parse.php http://php.net/manual/en/function.oci-bind-by-name.php

Comment: can someone give me more hint..still not working....u.u

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use the following function. Prepared statements are definitely preferred by most, but this is a good alternative:

```
<?php 
function mysql_escape_mimic($inp) { 
    if(is_array($inp)) 
        return array_map(__METHOD__, $inp); 

    if(!empty($inp) && is_string($inp)) { 
        return str_replace(array('\\', "\0", "\n", "\r", "'", '"', "\x1a"), array('\\\\', '\\0', '\\n', '\\r', "\\'", '\\"', '\\Z'), $inp); 
    } 

    return $inp; 
}
```

So you would replace this line:

`$condition .= "VIDEO_TITLE LIKE '%".mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $text)."%' OR ";`

with:

`$condition .= "VIDEO_TITLE LIKE '%".mysql_escape_mimic($connect, $text)."%' OR ";`

I borrowed it from here: http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php#101248

Comment: thank you for ur help i dont have any errors now but it isnt working.... it says Data not Found even if i searched data i have...

Comment: since mysql_escape_mimic has no connection to the db right?

Comment: @KwanheeHwang, absolutely not, it just transforms strings and protects against most kinds of SQL injections.